# Benchmarking retrieval in cloudant

Tags: database, couchdb, cloudant

I want to retrieve a set of keys from a cloudant db. I tried a few ways. However, custom_result performs lightning fast as compared to other methods. Can someone explain why?

```
from cloudant import cloudant
import json
import time
from cloudant.result import Result,ResultByKey


with open('credentials.json') as f:
    cred  = json.load(f)

with cloudant(str(cred['credentials']['username']),str(cred['credentials']['password']),url=str(cred['credentials']['url'])) as client:
    my_database = client['my_database']

    #Using POST
    payload = {"keys": ["012","345"]}
    end_point = '{0}/{1}'.format(client.server_url, 'my_database/_all_docs')
    params = {'include_docs': 'true'}
    start = time.time()
    response = client.r_session.post(end_point, data=json.dumps(payload), params=params)
    end = time.time()
    print end-start


    #using custom_result
    start = time.time()
    result = my_database.custom_result(include_docs=True,keys=["012","345"])
    end = time.time()
    print end-start


    #using all_doc
    start = time.time()
    result = my_database.all_docs(include_docs=True,keys=["012","345"]) 
    end = time.time()
    print end-start


    #using iteration
    keys=["012","345"]
    start = time.time()
    result=[]
    result_collection = Result(my_database.all_docs, include_docs=True)
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        result.append(result_collection[ResultByKey(i)]) 
    end = time.time()
    print end-start
```

My output is as follows:

```
0.426064968109
4.10079956055e-05
0.409541845322
0.819295167923
```

Can someone tell me why custom_result performs so fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function database.custom_result() only creates the cloudant.result.Result instance, no results are returned from Cloudant. You can try test it this way, end-start will be the whole time you get response from Cloudant.

```
start = time.time()
with database.custom_result(include_docs=True) as result:
  data = result[:]
end = time.time()
print end-start
```